# Can't see third div. Overflows another one

Tags: html, css, overflow

Hey guys I don't know what is wrong with my code. But page3 overflows page2. But i need them to come one after another. I copy pasted page2 and just changed the class name.

```css
.main {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("landbackground2.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center bottom;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.main-content {
  padding: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.icon {
  padding: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}


#main-h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}



/* NOTE: PAGE 2 */


.page2 {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("page2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

}

.page2-content {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: white 0px 0px 20px;
}

.bg-attach {
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.page3 {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(".jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}



.fuck {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Labby\bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.2\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Labby\css\font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Labby\landing pages\landpage.css">
  <title>Landing Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="overlay">
      <header>
        <div class="header">
          <p class="logo">Road trip</p>
          <i class="fa fa-bars icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="main-content">
        <h1 id="main-h1">This is Road Trip</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="page2">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="page2-content">
        <h1 >This is Road Trip</h1>
        <h2>21.12.2112</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure nam, nihil blanditiis.</p>
        <div class="btn">
          <a href="#">Learn more . . .</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page3">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="page3-content">
        <h1 >This is Road Trip</h1>
        <h2>21.12.2112</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure nam, nihil blanditiis.</p>
        <div class="btn">
          <a href="#">Learn more . . .</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>








  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want elements to follow each other - in the natural flow of the page - then don't use absolute positioning. They will appear after each other naturally.

Comment: that works but in that case i can't use top or left to center my main content. The content on page2 takes it's beginnig from the top of fisrt page.

Comment: If you are talking about `.main-content` then you can still absolutely position that. It is a block that you *don't* want in the natural flow.

Comment: there is margin, padding, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.main {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("landbackground2.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center bottom;
}

.overlay {
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.main-content {
  padding: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}

.icon {
  padding: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}


#main-h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}



/* NOTE: PAGE 2 */


.page2 {
  position:relative;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("page2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

}

.page2-content {
  position:absolute;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}
.page3-content {
  position:absolute;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: white 0px 0px 20px;
}

.bg-attach {
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.page3 {
position:relative;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(".jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}



.fuck {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Labby\bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.2\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Labby\css\font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Labby\landing pages\landpage.css">
  <title>Landing Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="overlay">
      <header>
        <div class="header">
          <p class="logo">Road trip</p>
          <i class="fa fa-bars icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="main-content">
        <h1 id="main-h1">This is Road Trip</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="page2">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="page2-content">
        <h1 >This is Road Trip</h1>
        <h2>21.12.2112</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure nam, nihil blanditiis.</p>
        <div class="btn">
          <a href="#">Learn more . . .</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page3">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="page3-content">
        <h1 >This is Road Trip</h1>
        <h2>21.12.2112</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure nam, nihil blanditiis.</p>
        <div class="btn">
          <a href="#">Learn more . . .</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>








  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Rufat No problem :) Make sure to accept it. Cheers

Comment: @RufatAliyev What do you mean jumps up? If you're referring to the snippet, don't mind that just view it on full page and try to resize. And it's jumping because you have a big padding set to your blocks on page2 and page3.

Comment: exactly. thanks a lot. I ticked the answer if you means accpeting by that. I am newbie here

Comment: @RufatAliyev Yeah that's what accepting the answer means here ;) and No problem. You can make use of % padding so it is responsive according to the viewport size or just reduce the padding altogether.